# Find a column with one value for 2 different dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

table 1

columns are as following:

```
date , time , user_id , channel
```

I wish to find for a list of USERS watching in 2 different DATES ,  channel(lets say CNN, NBC...)  all the entries relevant.

Means the channel in DATE 1 and DATE 2 is the same, also the user_id.

I try allready following:

```
select distinct  monthname(date),max(date), min(date) count(distinct user_id)   
from iptv_clean 
group by  monthname(date) 
having min(date)!= max(date)
```

But it seems not to work well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some example data and expected results. I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gives a list of users and channels that users watched on more than one date:

```
select user_id, channel, count(distinct date)   
from iptv_clean 
group by user_id, channel
having count(distinct date) > 1;
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: I keep getting the old results, well they are not right. i try select count(distinct user_id), monthname(date),channel, count(distinct date)   
from iptv_clean 
group by monthname(date)
having count(distinct date) > 1; maybe there is a way to declare that both dates are different and channel is the same? Don't know for sure...

Comment: @user3277266 . . . You need to edit your question and provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: I was using a different query that looks for the nr. of distinct users. With the query as you wrote, I get the simple nr. of distinct users. The query you wrote doesn't shows me the nr. of all users that watched the same channel in different days as I wished. I am not sure how I can modify the query to get the results expected.

Comment: @user3277266 . . . You should edit your question (or delete this question and ask a new one), including sample data and desired results.  I have no idea what you really want.